# ofstream outputfile() in while loop usually makes empty file

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I encountered a funny issue with this code but I am wondering why this happened:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define BUTTON_PORT 25
#define FILE_PATH "/path/to/output.txt"


int main(void) {

    int buttonState = 0;
    int pastButtonState = 0;
    int buttonCounter = 0;

    if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1) return 1;
    pinMode(BUTTON_PORT, INPUT);

    while(buttonCounter < 100){

        if (buttonState == 1 && pastButtonState == 0) buttonCounter++;

        usleep(100);
        ofstream outputfile(FILE_PATH);
        outputfile << buttonCounter << endl;
        outputfile.flush();
        outputfile.close();

        pastButtonState = buttonState;

    }
```

I expected `output.txt` to show current # of `buttonCounter`,
but file is always empty, and 1 of 10 times the file shows # of `buttonCounter`.
(with continuously exec `less /path/to/output.txt`)

I know certain repeat of `ofstream outputfile` in `while` loop is not a good solution, but I have no idea why `output.txt` is usually empty.

I might think it's ugly to use `ofstream outputfile` in `while` loop since `ofstream outputfile` takes some time since it's a bit high-level function.

---

While putting `outputfile` -related function into

```
if (buttonState == 1 && pastButtonState == 0) {...}
```

works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Sidenote: The `flush` and `close` are not necessary. `endl` already flushed, the file will be flushed on close, and the file will be closed on destruction when the file goes out of scope at the end of the loop body.

Comment: Just check the documentation what creating an `ofstream` means and does.

Comment: Just a note that you should prefer constant variables to macros.

Answer (score 2):

I would a add check to make sure the file was opened successfully. Also, the results of executing `less` on the file is not a reliable method to test the contents of the file while you are running the program. `usleep(100)` does not give you enough time to check the contents of the file before it is opened again.

I suggest the following change to your code.

```
while(buttonCounter < 100){

   if (buttonState == 1 && pastButtonState == 0) buttonCounter++;

   writeToFile(buttonCounter, FILE_PATH);
   showContentsOfFile(FILE_PATH);
   `
   pastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

where `writeToFile` is:

```
void writeToFile(int buttonState, std::string const& file)
{
   std::ofstream outputfile(file);
   if ( outputfile )
   {
      outputfile << buttonCounter << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cerr << "Unable to open " << file << " for writing to.\n";
   }
}
```

and `showContentsOfFile` is:

```
void showContentsOfFile(std::string const& file)
{
   std::ifstream inputfile(file);
   if ( outputfile )
   {
      int buttonCounter;
      if ( inputfile >> buttonCounter )
      {
         std::cout << "Button counter: " << buttonCounter << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
         std::cerr << "Unable to read buttonCounter from file " << file << std::endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      std::cerr << "Unable to open " << file << " for reading from.\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. with those functions, I can validate file is properly opened.

Comment: and with `tail -f` it shows correct answer and warnings `'file truncated.'` this might show file opened with `ofstream` should not properly attracted with `cat` or `less`.